# How to make a label transparant on a moving picture box (keeping it in the middle)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to achieve a somewhat animated menu for a game I intend to create and am running into the issue of making my labels transparent while keeping them centered in the middle of the screen. Obviously, parenting the object simply makes it move with the picture box, so is there any way to avoid this whilst creating transparent labels?

Comment: If you're making a game it's arguably better to create a `UserControl` where you can _render_ whatever you want (including transparency) rather than mucking about with picturebox

Comment: If you have a picture box that's moving around behind the "transparent" control, I suggest you use WPF as your UI framework, and not winforms, and here is why:
Winforms does not support transparency of controls. It mimics transparency by using the control's parent background to draw the background of the control. This leads to all kind of issues when using "transparent" controls that that overlap other controls. Moving controls behind a "transparent" control would force you to refresh your "transparent" control constantly, resulting in a flickering effect at best.